# reverse SQL LIKE

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is it possible in SQL (more specifically PostreSQL) to match a string against the pattern stored in the table so that when I have a DB field containing `%some%` I'd be able to select its row by something like

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE field_value LIKE 'Awesome stuff'
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    table_name
WHERE   'Awesome stuff' LIKE field_value
```